# FullCalendar limit amount of selectable time in scheduler

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs, scheduler, fullcalendar-scheduler

In my scheduler view, I'm trying to limit the amount of time a user can select to a maximum of 4 hours.  I thought that `selectConstraint` would be the ticket, but don't see a way to apply a max selectable duration.

I was hoping for something along the lines of `selectConstraint: {duration: '04:00'}`  or perhaps `duration: '240'` (in minutes).

Or... maybe limit the number of selectable slots??  I have it broken up into 15 minute increments, so is there a way to limit the select to a maximum of 16 slots?

I've been scouring the  [FullCalendar Docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/) (which is I think is rather poor IMO...), but I can't seem to find the key ingredient.

Anyone?

```
$('#schedulerCalendar').fullCalendar({
     defaultView: 'agendaDay',
     defaultDate: moment(systemDate),
     eventClick: $scope.eventClick,
     editable: true,
     eventOverlap: false,
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
     select: $scope.dayClick,
     slotDuration : '00:15:00',
     slotEventOverlap: false,
     allDaySlot: false,

     // Display only business hours (8am to 5pm)
     minTime: "08:00",
     maxTime: "17:00",

     businessHours: {
         dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Thursday
         start: '08:00', // start time (8am)
         end: '17:00', // end time (5pm)
     },

    hiddenDays: [ 0, 6 ],  // Hide Sundays and Saturdays

    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        callback($scope.eventSources);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use fullCalendar's [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectAllow/) and moment duration [asHours](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/) functions:

```
$('#schedulerCalendar').fullCalendar({  
    //....
    selectAllow: function(selectInfo) { 
         var duration = moment.duration(selectInfo.end.diff(selectInfo.start));
         return duration.asHours() <= 4;
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: Oh man... thank you!  Excellent and very fast answer.  :-)  Have a great weekend.

Comment: O  boy, if you were in my location, I am gone give a grand party to you for this :)