# zettwerk.fullcalendar - Is it possible to limit selection to one day in whole-day selections/month view?

Tags: fullcalendar, plone-4.x

I'm using zettwerk.fullcalendar in a Plone Site and I am trying to restrict 'day' selections (i.e. Month View seletions and whole day selections) to 1 day.

Other questions mention enableConstract and selectConstraint.

[How to limit timeslot selection to one day in Fullcalendar Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716706/how-to-limit-timeslot-selection-to-one-day-in-fullcalendar-jquery)

So I tried two approaches, in setting defaultCalendarOptions, I added:

```
'enableConstraint':{'start':'00:01',
                    'end':'23:59'
                 }
```

I could still select multiple days, so I tried:

```
'selectConstraint':{'start':'00:00',
                    'end':'23:59',
                 }
```

Unfortunately, that did not work either.
Is it possible or is selectConstraint/enableConstraint only for limiting the selection of hours?

The version of fullcalendar being used by zettwerk.fullcalendar is 1.6.4.

Comment: You can use `selectAllow` callback. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/44552761/8150882. Change that example 4 hours limit to 24 and should be good to go.

Comment: I found out the problem and there's not much I can do about it, but zettwerk.fullcalendar uses fullcalendar 1.6.4, which doesn't support 'enableConstraint' or 'selectConstraint.'
Unfortunately, it doesn't support 'selectAllow' either.